# How to make text Bold of the Item selected with Checkbox in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to make checked Items in Bold Format in QT DOM Model.
For the full code please follow the Git link.
https://github.com/aviralarpit/QTreeView_with_XML

```
    QVariant DomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    const QDomNode node = item->node();
    if ( role == Qt::CheckStateRole && (index.column() == 0) && hasChildren(index) )
        return static_cast< int >( item->isChecked() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked );
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    switch (index.column()) {
        case 0:
            return node.nodeName();
        case 1:
        {
            const QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = node.attributes();
            QStringList attributes;
            for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.count(); ++i) {
                QDomNode attribute = attributeMap.item(i);
                attributes << attribute.nodeName() + "=\""
                              + attribute.nodeValue() + '"';
            }
            return attributes.join(' ');
        }
        case 2:
            return node.nodeValue().split('\n').join(' ');
        default:
            break;
    }
    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

Flag function

```
Qt::ItemFlags DomModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    if ( index.column() == 0 )
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
    return flags;
}
```

setData function

```
bool DomModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    if (index.column() == 0 ){
        if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
            return false;
        }
        if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
            item->setChecked(value.toBool());
            emit dataChanged(index, index);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QAbstractItemModel::setData(index, value, role);
}
```

[image: Like the selected checkboxes should have Bold Fonts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `data()` function add a case for the `Qt::FontRole` item data role. Then just return a `QFont` instance that looks whathever you want it to look like, depending on the item's check state.

```
if (role == Qt::FontRole && item->isChecked()) {
        QFont font;
        font.setBold(true);
        return font;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the exact code what I need to change for Bold fonts? I am new to coding so its little hard for me. Thankyou

Comment: if (role == Qt::FontRole && item->isChecked())
        return QFont::Bold; // So far I hace implemented this but it doesn't work